# New Process Template not applied after upload

Tags: tfs

I'm working on setting up a new installation of TFS, and I seem to be having some issues getting an updated version of a process template applied to my project.  Here's what I've attempted so far:

- Tried to update the existing Agile process template; but it was locked down (and apparently you can't change this).  OK; not a big deal; I'll create a new template; and create a new project as you can't change the workflow of an existing one.
- Created a new project; applied the new template (which only has a few new transitions & states applied to work item types) and everything looks good.
- Now, i wanted to tweak this a little further; adding in a few new transitions.  Updated the workflow, uploaded it back to the server, and that process went fine.  However, my new transitions aren't showing up.
- If I create a new project using the same process template my new transitions show up in that one.

Any ideas on how I can get the new template applied to an existing project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply the changes to the project with the [`witadmin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236914.aspx) command.

Comment: So looking at the documentation; I'm not sure what command I'd use to apply the updated template to the project.  Is it the 'rebuild cache' option?I can export & import using the process template manager utility; and newly created projects get the updated process template; it's just the existing ones that dont

Comment: Hmm; I also don't seem to have the witadmin exe in the location the documentation says it would be

Comment: XML Process templates are applied at the time of team project creation. If you need to change the behavior of anything in a team project after it's created, you have to manually apply the changes. The `witadmin` utility is how that's accomplished. You need Visual Studio (or at least Team Explorer) installed to use it.

Comment: Ah; i gotcha.  All makes sense now.  I acutally downloaded a tool called tfs witadmin that wraps a gui around the command line.  Works like a charm.  Shame i can only upvote you once.  Saved me a ton of time.